# How transform JSX code in browser

Tags: reactjs, testing

Which answer is correct

- With Babel stand alone build
- Standard Babel and react preset
- JSX transformer is recommended by Facebook starting from ReactJs v0.15
- You cant use JSX in browser, must transpile it to ES5 before sending to browser

i choose 4 option (You cant...) but in right answer is 2(Standard B..), Can you explain WHY?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSX is a syntax sugar over JavaScript. When you use jsx in browser, JSX transformer needs some time to transform jsx to javascript. Using babel library you transpile your jsx to javascript, so in browser it will work faster than non-compile jsx